# MalformedURLException when deserializing URL

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I use Apache Commons to retrieve files from a remote server using sftp. I the URL to the file is stashed away and serialized. When deserializing it I get the following exception

> java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: sftp

The same thing happens when I do this

```
new URL(url.toString());
```

Where url is the url to the file retrieved by apache commons. I have aded the dependency to both apache commons and jsch. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please add the string contains `url.toString()`

Comment: sftp://username:password@host/tfs/TFS_files/PA/report.pdf

Comment: Try using the lib jsch

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch

Answer (score 0):

From java [documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) :

If this class does not exist, or if the class exists but it is not a subclass of URLStreamHandler, then a MalformedURLException is thrown.
Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist on the search path :-
http, https, ftp, file, and jar

Seems sftp is not supported.

Comment: But how can I have a URL with sftp as protocol turn it into a string and then when converting it back get an error? How could it be created from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better alternative would be http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/
In case you need or you are forced to use Apache libraries, there is an example how to do it http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/06/sftp-apache-commons-file-download.html

This should help you to get oriented, what do you trying to achieve.